# Nested rectangles

Tags: tikz-styles

I am trying to get this figure:

[image]

The figure is generated by the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes,backgrounds,arrows}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{bigbox} = [minimum width=3.5cm, minimum height=4.2cm,draw, thick, rounded corners, rectangle]
\tikzstyle{bigbox2} = [minimum width=2cm, draw, thick, rounded corners, rectangle]
\tikzstyle{box} = [minimum width=2.7cm, rounded corners,rectangle]

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1.5cm,draw,inner sep=0pt}]
 \node [txtstyle] (n1) {};
 \node [txtstyle,xshift=2cm] (n2) {};   
 \node [txtstyle,xshift= 4cm] (n3) {}; 
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={text width=2cm,anchor=north west,text height=2.86cm,draw}]
\node [txtstyle,xshift=4.985cm,yshift=0.76cm] (n4) {};

\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={text width=5.77cm,anchor=north west,text height=0.3cm,text centered}]
\node [txtstyle,xshift=-1.01cm,yshift=-0.733cm,draw] (n5) {}; %
\node [txtstyle,xshift=-1.01cm,yshift=-1.27cm,draw] (n6) {}; %
\node [txtstyle,xshift=-1.01cm,yshift=-1.8cm,draw] (n7) {}; %
     \node  at (n5.north west){Query Compiler};
     \node  at (n6.north west){Query Optimizer};
     \node  at (n7.north west){Query Executor};

\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={text width=2cm,anchor=north west,text centered}]
     \node  at (n1.north west){Command \\ Line \\ Interface}; 
     \node  at (n2.north west){Web \\ Interface};  
     \node  at (n3.north west){JDBC/ \\ ODBC \\ Server};
     \node  at (n4.north west){ ~\\ ~\\  ~\\ Meta \\ Data \\~ \\};
\end{scope}

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \node[bigbox] [fit = (n1) (n4)] (box) {};
\end{pgfonlayer}

\node[box,above of=n1,xshift=0.5cm] (us) {Upper System Level};
%
%
%
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={minimum width=2cm,minimum height=0.5cm,rounded corners,inner sep=0pt}]
  \node [txtstyle,below of=box,yshift=-2.5cm,draw] (h1) {Master};
  \node [txtstyle,below left of=h1,yshift=-0.5cm,xshift=-2.3cm,draw] (h2) {Slave};
  \node [txtstyle,below  of=h1,yshift=-0.3cm] (h3) {...};
  \node [txtstyle,below right of=h1,yshift=-0.5cm,xshift=2.3cm,draw] (h4) {Slave};
  \node [txtstyle,above of=h2,yshift=0.3cm] (hd) {Hadooop};
\end{scope}

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \node[bigbox2] [fit = (hd) (h4)] (box2) {};

 \draw[<->,>=latex', shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt,thick] (h1.200) to (h2.north);
 \draw[<->,>=latex', shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt,thick] (h1.340) to (h4.north);
   \draw[
        -triangle 90,
        line width=1.5mm,
        postaction={draw, line width=0.4cm, shorten >=0.2cm, -}
    ] (box.south) -- (box2.north);
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is a combination of a bunch of code I found on this site. It generates what I want, except that it complains about the `\tikzstyle` command, indicating that it doesn't know what it is and that it will ignore it (yet it generates what I want when I force it to complete compilation). The code seems quite crude and inelegant. In my quest to learn tikz better, I thought I would ask the experts on this forum if there is a cleaner way of achieving what I wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find a slightly more elegant solution using split rectangles and alignment. This at least removes some of the finagling with the placement of individual boxes. Perhaps this is useful.

```
  \documentclass[10pt]{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes,backgrounds,arrows}

  \begin{document} 

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzstyle{bigbox} = [minimum width=3.5cm, minimum height=4.2cm,draw, thick, rounded corners, rectangle]
  \tikzstyle{bigbox2} = [minimum width=2cm, draw, thick, rounded corners, rectangle]
  \tikzstyle{box} = [minimum width=2.7cm, rounded corners,rectangle]
  \tikzstyle{vbox} = [minimum width=2.7cm,rectangle,inner sep = -0.8pt]
  \tikzset{txtstyle/.style={text=black}}

 \node[align=center,draw,shape=rectangle split,
      rectangle split horizontal,
      rectangle split parts=3, text width=2cm,text centered] (A)
       {Command \\ Line \\ Interface\nodepart{two}Web \\ Interface\nodepart{three}JDBC/ \\ ODBC \\ Server};

 \node [align=center,draw,shape=rectangle split,
   rectangle split parts=3, text width=6.5cm,text centered,anchor=north] (B) at (A.south) 
    {Query Compiler\nodepart{two}Query Optimizer\nodepart{three}Query Executor};

 \node[vbox][fit=(A) (B)] (virtual) {};
 \node[align=center,shape=rectangle,draw,text width=1.5cm,text height=0.68cm,anchor=west] (C) at (virtual.east) { ~\\ ~\\ Meta \\ Data \\~ \\~ \\};

  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node[bigbox] [fit = (virtual) (C)] (box) {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}

  \node[box,above of=A,xshift=-1.5cm] (us) {Upper System Level};

  \begin{scope}[every node/.style={minimum width=2cm,minimum height=0.5cm,rounded corners,inner sep=0pt}]
    \node [txtstyle,below of=box,yshift=-2.5cm,draw] (h1) {Master};
    \node [txtstyle,below left of=h1,yshift=-0.5cm,xshift=-2.3cm,draw] (h2) {Slave};
    \node [txtstyle,below  of=h1,yshift=-0.3cm] (h3) {...};
    \node [txtstyle,below right of=h1,yshift=-0.5cm,xshift=2.3cm,draw] (h4) {Slave};
    \node [txtstyle,above of=h2,yshift=0.3cm] (hd) {Hadooop};
  \end{scope}

  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node[bigbox2] [fit = (hd) (h4)] (box2) {};

   \draw[<->,>=latex', shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt,thick] (h1.200) to (h2.north);
   \draw[<->,>=latex', shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt,thick] (h1.340) to (h4.north);
   \draw[->,>=latex', shorten >=2pt, thick] (box.south) to (box2.north);
     \draw[
          -triangle 90,
          line width=1.5mm,
       postaction={draw, line width=0.4cm, shorten >=0.2cm, -}
   ] (box.south) -- (box2.north);
  \end{pgfonlayer}

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is about `txtstyle` not being defined, not about `\tikzstyle`. This needs to be defined somewhere so you could just say:

```
\tikzset{txtstyle/.style={text=black}}
```

or what every style you want applied when `txtstyle` is used.

Your code uses `\tikzstyle`, which should be using `\tikzset` as per [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles).

Comment: Whoops, thanks for catching that. I missed it and the correction fixes things. I am still interested in finding a more elegant way of doing this.